# Change arc segments in a polyline feature to line segments in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, densify

A similar question has been asked here before and I have looked at the answers but in my case I need a different answer/solution.

I have a polyline dataset and some of the features have a combination of arc & straight line segments. If I use the Densify tool specifying a distance (x), the result is as expected for the arc segments (they get broken into line segments of x distance), however the segments that were already straight lines also have vertices inserted into them making numerous excess vertices.

Is there are way to only have the arc segments densified and not the straight line segments densified?

There are way too many features that I need to work on to do this manually.

Comment: You may try a second steep with the "Simplify Line" tool with a small tolerance to remove the extra vertices on the straight part

Comment: Or split your line at vertices, select the arc, densify the selected feature to get segment and then merge to reconstruct the original line

Comment: Please include a link to the previous similar question.

Answer (score 1):

I have realised that the Densify tool will achieve what I need it to by not using the "Distance" Densification Method but rather the "Angle" method. This effectively only converts the arc segments in the feature to line segments. It just means playing with the Maximum Deflection Angle & Maximum Vertex Count to achieve the desired number of inserted vertices for different radius curves.